# jQuery function source code

Tags: jquery

jQuery 1.4.2 in IE 8

When I call `$.isFunction(function() {})` it returns `true`.
Source code `isFunction` function:

```
    isFunction: function (obj) {
        return toString.call(obj) === "[object Function]";
    },
```

When I write in console `toString.call(function() {}) === "[object Function]"` it throws `"Object doesn't support this property or method"`.

Source code of minified version:

```
isFunction:function(a){return $.call(a)==="[object Function]"}
```

When I write in console `$.call(function() {})==="[object Function]"` it returns `false`.
Why code works in different ways?

Comment: What are you actually asking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of the [JQuery 1.4.2 source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js) (**inside the wrapper**), `toString` is defined as `Object.prototype.toString`. The global `toString` function is different from the prototyped `toString` method, hencethe different results.

```
// Save a reference to some core methods
toString = Object.prototype.toString,
```

Answer (score 1):

**this** is the truth :

```
 alert(   Object.prototype.toString.apply(t)    );
```